# Descending order of decimals

Tags: java, list, sorting, bigdecimal

It is requested to sort the list below from smallest to largest.

Array input: [-100, 50, 0, 56.6, 90, 0.12, .12, 02.34, 000.000]

My Code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    String[] s = new String[n + 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      s[i] = sc.next();
    }

    sc.close();
    List <String> k = new ArrayList <> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 2; i++) {
      k.add(s[i]);
    }

    Collections.sort(k, Collections.reverseOrder());
    k.toArray(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote the above code but I am getting this result.

My Output: [90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 000.000, 0.12, 0, .12, -100]

The expected result is like this.

Expected: [90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 0.12, .12, 0, 000.000, -100]

I tried converting array into list and sort it but it was able to sort positive and negative numbers but not decimal

Comment: Off Topic: `Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);`  Use of `sc.close()` can also close `System.in`. If you close a `Scanner` Object that wraps `System.in`, be sure you will  no longer need to use `System.in`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is the fact that you are not comparing doubles, you are comparing strings. Collections.sort() will call the String.compareTo() method which is leading to the behavior you are experiencing. The following code outputs the array you were expecting.

```
    String[] yourArray = {"-100","50","0","56.6","90","0.12",".12","02.34","000.000"};
    List<Double> k = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
        k.add(Double.parseDouble(yourArray[i]));
    }
    Collections.sort(k, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(k.get(i) + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Note: this will not output `000.000` or `0`, but `0.0` (similar for other values `90` -> `90.0`) ((no idea if that is relevant or not))

Answer (score 1):

Your code imports `BigDecimal`, but doesn't use it. Try the following:

Change this:

```
String []s=new String[n+2];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  s[i]=sc.next();
}
```

To this:

```
BigDecimal [] s = new BigDecimal[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  s[i]=sc.nextBigDecimal();
}
```

And change

`List<String> k = new ArrayList<>();`

to

`List<BigDecimal> k = new ArrayList<>();`

Consider removing the intermediate array, and using your Scanner to put a new `BigDecimal` into `k`:

```
 List<BigDecimal> k = new ArrayList<> ();
 for (int i < 0; i < n; i++) {
    k.add (sc.nextBigDecimal());
 }
```

### Note:

The `sort` method of `Collections` is *stable*. That means, it will  not change the order of two objects that compare as equal.

`BigDecimal.compareTo` regards `0.00`,  `0.0000`, and `0` as equal to each other. The values `123`, `123.00`, `123.000` are another example. So, in your example, if `0` precedes `000.000` before the sort, `0` will precede `000.000` after the sort. If `000.000` precedes `0` before the sort, `000.000` will precede `0` after the sort. If that is an issue for you, you can create a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html), which might use the [`scale` method of BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale()). Another option is to create a custom class, which implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are just sorting the value as strings.  What you want to do is sort them as if they are doubles.  You need to provide a comparator that compare the double values instead of string.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String []s = {"-100","50","0","56.6","90","0.12",".12","02.34","000.000"};
  System.out.println("Before  : " + Arrays.toString(s));
  Arrays.sort(s, (x,y)->Double.valueOf(y).compareTo(Double.valueOf(x)));
  System.out.println("Actual  : " + Arrays.toString(s));
  System.out.println("Expected: [90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 0.12, .12, 0, 000.000, -100]");
 }
}
```

output

```
Before  : [-100, 50, 0, 56.6, 90, 0.12, .12, 02.34, 000.000]
Actual  : [90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 0.12, .12, 0, 000.000, -100]
Expected: [90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 0.12, .12, 0, 000.000, -100]
```